# Why are wiki tag descriptions cut off at the words 'used to'?

Tags: discussion, wiki, tags

Looking at the [tags page](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/tags) the wiki description of some tags is cut off. It seems to be anything before the words 'used to ' is chopped. Look a 'gear' and 'mash'. It seems intentional. I was just wondering why.

[image: cut off]

Here is the full description if you roll over:

[image: full]

Comment: It happens with 'This tag ' or if you start the entry with the name of the tag itself. Is there a list of these we-wont-show-this phrases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *magic*!

Er, ok, so it's a handful of patterns that are removed to try and reduce the amount of repetitious text on the tags page. You can find all the gritty details in [New tags page mangles tag wiki excerpts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82700/new-tags-page-mangles-tag-wiki-excerpts/82702#82702)

If it doesn't look right, re-work the tag excerpt wording a bit.

Comment: Thanks, I looked on SO for this but could not find it.